# Is there an alternative solution to prevent other profiles from seeing a certain profile's activites?

Tags: chatter, profile, field-level-security, role-hierarchy, roles

I have an original profile A

A group of users wanted to go from profile A to a new profile called profile B that is an exact mirror of profile A.

Profile B wants to create activities and task, but does not want profile A to see their activities and tasks.

The activities (Tasks & Events) sharing is based on the access to the parent record so if both the profiles have access to the Contact record, then they will see each other’s tasks.

If there profiles are mirror images than clearly they can see each other's activities.

Is there an alternative solution that can be used for profile B to add activates and task privately?